# ScrollablePositionedList initial scroll offset

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview

I'm working with `ScrollablePositionedList` in flutter for a while. From the document I found, it said `ScrollablePositionedList` works slightly the same with `ListView`. My problem is that I want to set the initial index of the `ScrollablePositionedList` in the position around 70% of screen height from the top of the screen, and I intend to do with by setting the pixel for that initial index. However, I'm struggling to find how to set initial scroll offset for the `ScrollablePositionedList` with `ItemScrollController`. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can **set the initial index when building** the widget with `initialScrollIndex` and `initialAlignment` property. The alignment is a bit more complicated to use so I wrote a little function for you.

```dart
int initialIndex = 1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
       return ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
           initialScrollIndex: initialIndex,
           initialAlignment: getAlignment( 
              index: initialIndex,
              itemHeight: list[initialIndex].height,
              viewPortHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
              alignmentOnItem: 0.5, //middle of item
           ),
```

And here is the **calculation for the alignment**. You can configure in what position the item should be shown with `alignmentOnItem`.

```dart
double getAlignment({
    required int index,
    required double viewPortHeight,

    ///The item height at the [index]. If all your items have the same height this
    ///can be a static value
    required double itemHeight,

    ///A double value between |0, 1| is expected, where percentage of the item
    ///should be positioned based on the center of the screen.
    ///(0 is top of the item, 1 is bottom if the item)
    double alignmentOnItem = 0.5,
  }) {
    assert(alignmentOnItem >= 0 && alignmentOnItem <= 1,
        "Alignment on item is expected to be within 0 and 1");
    final relativePageHeight = 1 / viewPortHeight * itemHeight;
    return 0.5 - relativePageHeight * alignmentOnItem;
  }
```

Note that if you set the `alignmentOnItem` to something that cannot be reached (so that an overscroll happens) the desired position obviously cannot be reached. See alignment at index 0.